# Query to report disk space allocation and used space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, disk-space

We are using 6 databases in total for an application, and we can only share 4TB of space among all 6 auto-grow databases (via SAN storage).

I'd like to write a query (report) for a single database indicating the "Currently allocated space" and "Available free space" attributes under the Tasks > Shrink > Database option in SQL Server Management Studio.

Then I'd like to convert those numbers to TB and total each database to get a rough estimate of how much space we have left.  Can these fields be accessed via a T-SQL query?  If so, what would the query look like?

[image: Shrink Database Dialog]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is the query Management Studio uses to populate those numbers:

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(CAST(df.size as float)) FROM sys.database_files AS df 
   WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 ) ) AS [DbSize],
SUM(a.total_pages) AS [SpaceUsed],
(SELECT SUM(CAST(df.size as float)) FROM sys.database_files AS df 
   WHERE df.type in (1, 3)) AS [LogSize]
FROM
sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a 
  on p.partition_id = a.container_id 
left join sys.internal_tables it 
  on p.object_id = it.object_id
```

You need to perform math here just like Management Studio does in order to get the same numbers. Also, the left join to `sys.internal_tables` seems superfluous at best. So adjusting that query to match your ideal output:

```
SELECT
(SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(CAST(df.size as float))*8/1024.0)
   FROM sys.database_files AS df 
   WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 ) ) AS [DbSize],
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(a.total_pages)*8/1024.0) AS [SpaceUsed],
(SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(CAST(df.size as float))*8/1024.0)
   FROM sys.database_files AS df 
   WHERE df.type in (1, 3)) AS [LogSize]
FROM sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a 
  on p.partition_id = a.container_id;
```

With this update, assuming your database doesn't change in the meantime, it should yield:

```
753475.94    744030.07    2900.00
```

Doing some simple math, and isolating just the three numbers you want:

```
;WITH t(s) AS
(
  SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(size)*8/1024.0)
   FROM sys.database_files
   WHERE [type] % 2 = 0
), 
d(s) AS
(
  SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(total_pages)*8/1024.0)
   FROM sys.partitions AS p
   INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a 
   ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
)
SELECT 
  Allocated_Space = t.s, 
  Available_Space = t.s - d.s,
  [Available_%] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), (t.s - d.s)*100.0/t.s)
FROM t CROSS APPLY d;
```

Comment: Great script Aaron. My enviroment had an arithmetic overflow error though. I had to cast the size in the first CTE to something bigger.

Answer (score 25):

Aaron's query is good, but as an alternative, I use this query from Glenn Berry's [DMV Queries](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/tag/dmv-queries/)
(you would need to change the math for TBs):

```
-- Individual File Sizes and space available for current database
-- (Query 36) (File Sizes and Space)
SELECT f.name AS [File Name] , f.physical_name AS [Physical Name], 
CAST((f.size/128.0) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS [Total Size in MB],
CAST(f.size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0 AS DECIMAL(15,2)) 
AS [Available Space In MB], [file_id], fg.name AS [Filegroup Name]
FROM sys.database_files AS f WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS fg WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON f.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's some SQL that might work for you.

```
Create Table #dbInfo (dId smallint, dbName sysname, gId smallint NULL, segName varchar(256) NULL, 
       filName varchar(520) NULL, sizeMg decimal(10,2) null, 
       usedMg decimal(10,2) null, freeMg decimal(10,2) null, 
       pcntUsed decimal(10,2) null, pcntFree decimal(10,2) null)
Declare @sSql varchar(1000)
Set @sSql = 'Use [?];
Insert #dbInfo (dId, dbName, gid, segName, filName, sizeMg, usedMg)
Select db_id(), db_name(), groupid, rtrim(name), filename, Cast(size/128.0 As Decimal(10,2)), 
Cast(Fileproperty(name, ''SpaceUsed'')/128.0 As Decimal(10,2))
From dbo.sysfiles Order By groupId Desc;'
Exec sp_MSforeachdb @sSql
Update #dbInfo Set
freeMg = sizeMg - usedMg,
pcntUsed = (usedMg/sizeMg)*100,
pcntFree = ((sizeMg-usedMg)/sizeMg)*100

select * from #dbInfo compute sum(sizeMG),  sum(FreeMg) 
drop table #dbInfo
```

It's old SQL but still works.  One of these days I'm going to rewrite it to use the sys.database_files like the answer from Aaron.

Answer (score 8):

After working on a similar question ([Querying True Physical Database File Sizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142076/querying-true-physical-database-file-sizes/142087#142087)), I think a query that display the different file sizes, separated, e.g. by log and database, and the size of the file on disk would be more helpful to most users.

This includes the system file size and how much space it's taking on disk, as well as the SQL file size, SQL space used, and by extension SQL free space as well. It includes the full path of the file being evaluated.  A user would need to change the calculation for 'Size_On_Disk_Bytes' if the disk is formatted using an allocation size different from the default (4096 bytes).

```
SELECT fg.data_space_id AS FGID,
   (f.file_id) AS File_Id,
   -- As provided by OP, size on disk in bytes.
   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, CAST(f.size AS FLOAT) * 8.00 * 1024), 1), '.00','') AS Size_On_Disk_Bytes,
   ROUND((CAST(f.size AS FLOAT) * 8.00/1024)/1024,3) AS Actual_File_Size,
   ROUND(CAST((f.size) AS FLOAT)/128,2) AS Reserved_MB,
   ROUND(CAST((FILEPROPERTY(f.name,'SpaceUsed')) AS FLOAT)/128,2) AS Used_MB,
   ROUND((CAST((f.size) AS FLOAT)/128)-(CAST((FILEPROPERTY(f.name,'SpaceUsed'))AS FLOAT)/128),2) AS Free_MB,
   f.name,
   f.physical_name
FROM sys.database_files f 
    LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg
    ON f.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
```

In addition, this query will return information about the space on the volume drive that hosts the files.  The user will need to have access to sys.master_files.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dovs.logical_volume_name AS LogicalName,
dovs.volume_mount_point AS Drive,
CONVERT(INT,dovs.available_bytes/1048576.0) AS FreeSpaceInMB
FROM sys.master_files mf
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.FILE_ID) dovs
ORDER BY FreeSpaceInMB ASC
```

Comment: Upvoted for actually including the units (MB). Seems quite important to include.

Answer (score 0):

Something I put together. You NEED POWERSHELL on your SQL Server to run this. Not sure of the version. This will take your drive sizes and report back the file sizes and free space as well as free drive space.

It's not 100% original and parts of it I found elsewhere on the internet and put the whole thing together. It was a PITA to get it to fit into the right margins so you might have to play with the parentheses

```
--drop table ##DB_FILE_INFO
 --alter procedure super_drive_info3 

 --as

  if exists ( select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    where o.xtype in ('U') and o.name in ('##DB_FILE_INFO' ))
drop table ##DB_FILE_INFO

if exists ( select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    where o.xtype in ('U') and o.name in ('##output'))
drop table ##output

 create table ##DB_FILE_INFO (
[server_Name] varchar(255) not null,
[database_name] varchar(255) not null,
[File_ID]           int     not null,
[File_Type]     int     not null ,
[Drive]     varchar(255)    not null ,
[Logical_Name]      varchar(255)    not null ,
[Physical_Name]     varchar(255)    not null ,
[FILE_SIZE_MB]      int     not null ,
[SPace_USED_MB] int     not null ,
[Free_space]    int     not null ,
[Max_SIZE]      int     not null ,
[Percent_Log_growth_enabled]    int     not null ,
[growth_rate]   int     not null ,
[current_date]      datetime        not null
)
--go
declare @sql    nvarchar(4000)
set @sql =
'use ['+'?'+']
 --if db_name() <> N''?'' goto Error_Exit
 insert into ##DB_FILE_INFO
(
    [server_Name],
    [database_name],
    [File_ID],
[File_Type],
[Drive],
[Logical_Name],
[Physical_Name],
[FILE_SIZE_MB],
[SPace_USED_MB],
[Free_space],
[Max_SIZE],
[Percent_Log_growth_enabled],
[growth_rate],
[current_date]
)
SELECT 
@@servername as [Server_Name],
db_name() as database_name,
[file_id] AS [File_ID],
[type] AS [File_Type],
substring([physical_name],1,1) AS [Drive],
[name] AS [Logical_Name],
[physical_name] AS [Physical_Name],
CAST([size] as DECIMAL(38,0))/128. AS [File Size MB], 
CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name],''SpaceUsed'') AS DECIMAL(38,0))/128. AS 
[Space_Used_MB], 
(CAST([size] AS DECIMAL(38,0))/128) - 
(CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name],''SpaceUsed'') AS DECIMAL(38,0))/128.) AS [Free 
 Space],
[max_size] AS [Max_Size],
[is_percent_growth] AS [Percent_Growth_Enabled],
[growth] AS [Growth Rate],
getdate() AS [Current_Date]
FROM sys.database_files'
 exec sp_msforeachdb @sql
 declare @svrName varchar(255)
declare @sql2 varchar(400)
--by default it will take the current server name, we can the set the server 
name as well
set @svrName = @@SERVERNAME
set @sql2 = 'powershell.exe -c "Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ' + 
QUOTENAME(@svrName,'''') + ' -Class Win32_Volume -Filter ''DriveType = 3'' | 
select name,capacity,freespace | 

foreach{$_.name+''|
 ''+$_.capacity/1048576+''%''+$_.freespace/1048576+''*''}"'
 --creating a temporary table
 CREATE TABLE ##output
 (line varchar(255))
 --inserting  in to temporary table
 insert ##output
 EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql2;

 with Output2 
 --(drivename, capacity(gb),freespace(gb), always_on_status)
 as
 (
 select @@servername as server_name, 
rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX(':',line) -1))) as drivename
 ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
 (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as float)/1024,2) as 
 'capacityGB'
 ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
 (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as float) /1024 ,2)as 
 'freespaceGB'
 ,CASE WHEN (SERVERPROPERTY ('IsHadrEnabled')=1) THEN 'YES' WHEN 
 (SERVERPROPERTY ('IsHadrEnabled')=0) THEN 'NO'ELSE 'NOT AVAILABLE' END AS 
 ALWAYS_ON_STATUS
  --into #output2
 from ##output
   where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
   --order by drivename
  ),
  DB_FILE_INFO2 as
 (
 select server_Name,
    database_name,
    File_ID,
File_Type,
Drive,
Logical_Name,
Physical_Name,
FILE_SIZE_MB,
SPace_USED_MB,
Free_space,
Max_SIZE,
Percent_Log_growth_enabled,
growth_rate
--current_date 
from ##DB_FILE_INFO 
--inner join #output b on a.drive = b.drivename and a.server_Name = 
b.server_name
)
select  
getdate() as Today_Date,
a.server_Name,
a.database_name,
a.Drive,
a.Logical_Name,
a.Physical_Name,
a.FILE_SIZE_MB,
a.Space_Used_MB,
--sum(a.SPace_USED_MB) as hg,
a.Free_space as Free_Space_in_File,
 --Percentage_file_free = (a.Space_Used_MB/a.FILE_SIZE_MB),
b.capacitygb as Total_Drive_capacity,
b.freespacegb as Total_Free_Space,
c.total_log_size_mb,
c.active_log_size_mb
--,Percentage_free_space = ((cast(Free_space as decimal))/(cast(FILE_SIZE_MB 
as decimal)) * 100)

from DB_FILE_INFO2 a
inner join output2 b on a.server_Name = b.server_name and a.Drive = 
 b.drivename
cross apply sys.dm_db_log_stats (db_id(a.database_name)) c
order by a.Drive, a.database_name

--drop table ##DB_FILE_INFO
--drop table #output
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script can be used to get following information:
1. DB Size Info
2. FileSpaceInfo
3. AutoGrowth
4. Recovery Model
5. Log_reuse_backup information

```
CREATE TABLE #tempFileInformation
(
DBNAME          NVARCHAR(256),
[FILENAME]      NVARCHAR(256),
[TYPE]          NVARCHAR(120),
FILEGROUPNAME   NVARCHAR(120),
FILE_LOCATION   NVARCHAR(500),
FILESIZE_MB     DECIMAL(10,2),
USEDSPACE_MB    DECIMAL(10,2),
FREESPACE_MB    DECIMAL(10,2),
AUTOGROW_STATUS NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @SQL = '
 USE [?]
            INSERT INTO #tempFileInformation
            SELECT  
                DBNAME          =DB_NAME(),     
                [FILENAME]      =A.NAME,
                [TYPE]          = A.TYPE_DESC,
                FILEGROUPNAME   = fg.name,
                FILE_LOCATION   =a.PHYSICAL_NAME,
                FILESIZE_MB     = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0),
                USEDSPACE_MB    = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(A.SIZE/128.0 - ((A.SIZE - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME,''SPACEUSED'') AS INT))/128.0))),
                FREESPACE_MB    = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(A.SIZE/128.0 -  CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME,''SPACEUSED'') AS INT)/128.0)),
                AUTOGROW_STATUS = ''BY '' +CASE is_percent_growth when 0 then cast (growth/128 as varchar(10))+ '' MB - ''
                                                                  when 1 then cast (growth as varchar(10)) + ''% - '' ELSE '''' END
                                                                  + CASE MAX_SIZE WHEN 0 THEN '' DISABLED '' 
                                                                                  WHEN -1 THEN '' UNRESTRICTED''
                                                                                  ELSE '' RESTRICTED TO '' + CAST(MAX_SIZE/(128*1024) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '' GB '' END
                                                                + CASE IS_PERCENT_GROWTH WHEn 1 then '' [autogrowth by percent]'' else '''' end
    from sys.database_files A
    left join sys.filegroups fg on a.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
    order by A.type desc,A.name
    ;
    '

    --print @sql

    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL
    go

    SELECT dbSize.*,fg.*,d.log_reuse_wait_desc,d.recovery_model_desc
    FROM #tempFileInformation fg
    LEFT JOIN sys.databases d on fg.DBNAME = d.name
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        select dbname,
                sum(FILESIZE_MB) as [totalDBSize_MB],
                sum(FREESPACE_MB) as [DB_Free_Space_Size_MB],
                sum(USEDSPACE_MB) as [DB_Used_Space_Size_MB]
            from #tempFileInformation
            where  dbname = fg.dbname
            group by dbname
    )dbSize


go
DROP TABLE #tempFileInformation
```