# What caused the database [.mdf file] to grow suddenly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, auto-growth

I am trying to find the cause which have bloated the mdf of a database from 20 GB to 100 GB.

So far i tried checking the autogrow events to find time, but could not find none using standard reports and even default trace files.

We don't have 3rd party monitoring tools to confirm if any maintenance job like rebuild would have done or any other process.

How can i find what caused the growth on this mdf?

Comment: You didn't find any growth in any of the default trace files? Then it happened too long ago to still have a record of it. There's no other place where this is logged by default.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, unfortunately no.. But i found that we have trace files saved for past 2 months. how can i query them if possible to find the info

Comment: It's one of the examples I use here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48053/1186

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will find all of the autogrow activities in all of the errorlog files still in active sequence, from [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48053/1186):

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
   DatabaseName,
   HostName,
   ApplicationName,
   [FileName],
   SPID,
   Duration,
   StartTime,
   EndTime,
   FileType = CASE EventClass WHEN 92 THEN 'Data' ELSE 'Log' END
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass IN (92,93)
-- AND DatabaseName = N'AdventureWorks'
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Now, once you've identified a suspect autogrowth event, you can see information like the application name and host name that caused the event. It's *possible* that you might capture other activity by the same SPID, but you can't rely on this. Just take a look for things that started or ended within an arbitrary window - this looks at 5 minutes before and 5 minutes after, and hard-codes the SPID observed above:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
  WHERE StartTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, '2018-03-19 11:41:16.970')
    AND EndTime   <  DATEADD(MINUTE,  5, '2018-03-19 11:41:16.970')
    -- AND TextData IS NOT NULL
    AND SPID = 63;
```

If you are rolling through 20 errorlog files *per day*, something is not configured correctly or you are performing way too much of something that is filling those log files with noise. IMHO.

Comment: Per OP's comment on my answer: Does this only query the current file? Any easy way to walk through *all* old default trace files in that same folder? I suggested putting the file list in a table, then using a cursor to loop through and query each one.

Comment: @BradC The argument `,DEFAULT` tells it to go through all the files. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-trace-gettable-transact-sql): `If number_files is specified as default, fn_trace_gettable reads all rollover files until it reaches the end of the trace.` `@path` just points the function at the folder. It will find all the files in the folder, no need for a cursor, temp table, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Before asking *why* you should be asking *what*:

First, run a query like this to determine used/free space in each data/log file for the current database:

```
SELECT  dbname = DB_NAME(),
        filetype = type_desc,
        logical_name = name, 
        TotalMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),size/128.0),
        UsedMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')/128.0),
        FreeMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),(size - FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.0),
        MaxSizeMB = CASE WHEN max_size = -1 THEN NULL 
            ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 1), max_size / 128.0) END,
        GrowthRate=CASE WHEN is_percent_growth = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar(12),growth)+'%'
                WHEN growth = 0 THEN 'FIXED'
                ELSE CONVERT(varchar(12), growth/128) + 'MB' END,
        physical_name
 FROM sys.database_files WITH (NOLOCK)
 ORDER BY type, file_id;
```

Is the 100GB file actually full? Or is it mostly empty space?

If it is empty, you can do some planning to recover some of the empty space, [with all the appropriate caveats about shrinking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/180131/determining-what-objects-shrinkdatabase-will-free-space-from/180138#180138).

If it is full, use a query like this to find out what tables are using all the space:

```
SELECT s.Name AS SchemaName,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    max(p.rows) AS [RowCount],
    CONVERT(decimal(12,1),SUM(a.total_pages)/128.0) AS TotalSpaceMB, 
    CONVERT(decimal(12,1),SUM(a. used_pages)/128.0) AS UsedSpaceMB
FROM            sys.tables t
INNER JOIN  sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN  sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN  sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN  sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY t.Name, s.Name
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

If you know what table has grown, that should lead you back to whatever process might have contributed to it.

Comment: Thanks Brad, Is the 100GB file actually full? Or is it mostly empty space?--> It was mostly empty space. But i have a question on what filled this space

Comment: @BeginnerDBA I assume you've already checked the SQL errorlog and the SQL agent job history, and that you would have been aware of a scheduled reindex job or something. I could suggest ways to capture future activity if this happens routinely, but I'm not sure how to do that retroactively, if you didn't already have other monitors running. Sometimes the answer is unfortunately "I don't know, but I've set up a monitor so if it ever happens again we will be able to tell."